# CloudFront blue/green via Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, blue-green-deployment

I have two CloudFront distributions A and B.

Assigned CNAMEs to distribution A (blue.domain.com and domain.com) and created appropriate SSL certificates. In Route53 I can assign an alias for distribution (e.g. domain.com -> blue.domain.com)

Regarding to [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements) I can't assign the same CNAME to distribution B (green.domain.com and **domain.com**) because CNAME **domain.com** has already been assigned to distribution A.

I was intended to switch traffic between blue/green distributions using Route53. E.g. domain.com points blue.domain.com and then make domain.com points to green.domain.com

So this approach doesn't work. I've found another one:

- Update Route53 to anticipated CloudFront distribution
- Remove CNAME from Blue
- Add CNAME to Green

But it leads to both distributions A & B downtime and requires several manual steps.

Is there any different way to achieve blue/green switching?

Comment: Can you switch the origin of the distribution instead?

Comment: @jellycsc No I can't do that. I have two independent deployed stacks

Comment: As cloudfront identifies distribution from host header or sni, blue/green isn’t going to be smooth because adding removing cname may take time, origin failover could help .

Comment: @JamesDean It could help if CF behaviors would be the same in blue and green but they  can be different. So switching to different origin doesn't work for this scenario

Comment: If you don’t plan to change origin, falling back to a different distribution doesn’t make sense because cloudfront is shared and of something is wrong at cloudfront , it will affect others as well, however if origin has a problem so I guess you can use lambda@edge to change origin on the fly aa changing cname and alsp origin failover will take time , example in 504s, origin failover would wait till the timeout set.